# How-to install and run keen/dashboards

Tags: docker, keen-io

I forked the keen/dashboards github repo and I am trying to create a Dockerfile for running the dashboard in a Docker container.

My fork: https://github.com/adityai/dashboards

I am not familiar with node and npm. The Docker image was built successfully.

https://hub.docker.com/r/adityai/dashboards/

I am not sure if I am using the right command to start the dashboards app (npm start) because when I try to run the docker container locally, it does not start. It exits right away.

docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name=keen-dashboard adityai/dashboards:gh-pages

Answer (score 4):

Like you did: clone the repo

```
$ git clone https://github.com/adityai/dashboards.git
```

This repo does contain a Dockerfile (which is a file which describes the setup of your docker image). You can build a docker image from the file

```
$ cd dashboards
$ docker build -t my-dashboard .
```

The dockerfile starts from base image httpd (apache).
After the build of your dockerfile you can see your image:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
my-dashboard        latest              81a5607c03ba        About a minute ago   204 MB
```

And you can create a container instance from that image. I must admit there is not much info about the `docker run` command on the [github](https://github.com/adityai/dashboards) page or [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/adityai/dashboards/) page.

Now you can run the image. I saw that port 80 was exposed in the dockerfile so I mapped port 80 of the container on port 80 of my local machine.

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 my-dashboard
```

Now I can visit the dashboards in my browser at `localhost:80`
[image]